# Changing section name in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, section-titles

I used the code

```
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\scshape}{Problem \# \thesection}{0em}{}
```

and \section{} to create a section called ("Problem #"+section number). However, when I add \tableofcontents, the section name only appears to be the section number. How can I change it to a single "Problem #"+section number without being (section number + "Problem #" + section number)?

[image: What I have for the content (main body) of the file but not the table of content, and I want the sections in the table of content also in this form.]

[image: Table of Contents]

An example document is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\scshape}{Problem \# \thesection}
  {0em}{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{}
something something...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\titleformat` is not a standard command, presumably defined in some package you have not shown? please include a small one-section document with a table of contents that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question and a small document is included now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `titlesec` package is only for configuring the headings. However, as can be seen in [its documentation on CTAN](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), there is a suggestion to use the companion package `titletoc`, bundled with `titlesec`:

> ### 6. Contents: The titletoc package
>
> This package is a companion to the titlesec package and it handles toc entries. [...]

In particular, have a look at the `\titlecontents` command.
I have attached a simple continuation of your MWE.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\scshape}
    {Problem \# \thetitle}
    {0em}
    {}

\titlecontents
    {section}                       % which level does it apply to, e.g. chapter, section, ...
    [0pt]                           % left margin
    {}                              % code executed before the tocline
    {Problem \# \thecontentslabel}  % format for numbered entries
    {Problem \# \thecontentslabel}  % format for unnumbered entries
    {}                              % format for filler page
    []                              % code executed after tocline
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{}
 something something...
\end{document}
```